# Circular progress bar with indeterminate progress around a circular text view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, progress-bar

I want to place a circular progress bar around a circular textview. The progress needs to have indeterminate rotation. I have tried the following code but doesn't work at all.
Attaching an image for reference [image]

layout of activity -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:context=".onboarding.ui.WelcomeSplashFragment">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_50"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/laxmi_green"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDuration="100"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/character_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_50"
            android:background="@drawable/splash_character_ring_shape"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="V"
            android:textColor="@color/laxmi_green"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:text="@string/welcome_to"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_20"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/company_name_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/character_header"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_name_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:text="Vertigo Electronics"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_20"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/please_wait_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcome_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/please_wait_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tetris_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name_header" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

progress_indeterminate.xml -

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/circle"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

circle.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@color/laxmi_green" />
</shape>
```

After this code, i can see the progress bar around the textview but it is not rotating at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `android:useLevel="false"` in the `circle.xml`. Either Remove it or set `useLevel=true` and your progress shall work normally.

`useLevel` allows the drawable to be drawn partially and if you set it false then it won't be allowed to be drawn partially which is the case with progress.